# How can I make matplotlib forget about removed plot elements?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib within a GUI and elements come and go from the plot.  I'm trying to keep the axis tight on the data, but have noticed that if an element is removed, `axis('tight')` still expands the axis as though it were there.  How can this be addressed?

Example:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
h1 = ax.plot(1,1,'.')
h2 = ax.plot(10,10,'.')
h3 = ax.plot(20,20,'.')
ax.axis('tight')  # (1,20,1,20)
h3[0].remove()
ax.axis('tight')  # still (1,20,1,20), desire (1,10,1,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the element from the plot, call `ax.relim()` on the axis so that it recalculates the limits before calling `ax.axis('tight')`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
h1 = ax.plot(1,1,'.')
h2 = ax.plot(10,10,'.')
h3 = ax.plot(20,20,'.')
ax.axis('tight')  # (1,20,1,20)
h3[0].remove()
ax.relim()        # recalculates that limits for the axis
ax.axis('tight')  # will rescale the plot correctly to the new limits
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is what I needed.  Sadly, there is a bug that prevents it from working with imshow() plot data, at least on older versions.  I just plotted some little dots on the corners as a workaround.